# Spring MVC+JSP app to send page in email

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I've written a small Spring MVC+JSP app https://github.com/alexec/release-manager and I'd like to add a "watch page" function to it. The user can click to watch the page, and when some data changes, then it will send that page to the user in an email.

Any thoughts on how I might achieve it?

Comment: I assume you have some method that allows people to alter the page, or at least the data on the page.  My thought is you tie into that method, and when the changes are saved, call a service method that then gets a list of all the people marked as "watchers" and send an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you can use AOP ,create  such class in spring 
Pattern:

```
    @Aspect
    public class StateAOP {
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

// ..............................................................................
@Before("AllController()")
public void changeState(JoinPoint joinpoint) {
      service.changeStateOf()
                }}

    @Pointcut("within(com.control..*)")
public void AllController() {
 }

  // ..............................................................................
```

And also create a state class in session

```
    @Component
    @Scope("session")
    public class state
    {
    // static
     }

// ..............................................................................
```

and after that create ajax function usin jquery  interval  in web view read time to time state and in change send email